# How to syncdb when adding a new app and south is installed?

Tags: django, django-south

I've got a Django app with South installed. I added an app ("guardian") in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now when I run python `manage.py` `syncdb` I get:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.admin
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - myapp
 - guardian
```

and trying the migration returns:

```
Nothing seems to have changed.
```

Is there any way to use the original syncdb, not the South one?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `manage.py migrate --list guardian`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running `manage.py migrate guardian`?

*"Nothing seems to have changed"* looks like an output of running `manage.py schemamigration`, which wouldn't create any tables to begin with...

Answer (score -2):

You can remove "south" from INSTALLED_APPS then run syncdb and finally, add "south" to INSTALLED_APPS again.